# WCF and wsHttpBinding - Message encryption

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, wshttpbinding

I'm working on a client-server project implemented using `WCF`. The clients are deployed on different machines and communicate with services through the internet. I'm relatively new to `WCF`, and am a bit confused on choosing the appropriate binding for my Web services. The clients need to be authorized to perform operations, however, I'm implementing my own authentication algorithm and trying to avoid Windows authentication for various reasons, but I still need to make sure the message transferred in the channel is encrypted.

Right now I'm using `wsHttpBinding` with security mode set to `Message`. Full configuration looks like this:

[image]

I've set the authentication type in `IIS` to `Anonymous Authentication` to make sure the requests are passed through, and was expecting a service call to fail since `MessageClientCredentialType` in my binding is explicitly set to `Windows`. However, when I run the code, the service successfully gets called and returns the expected values. I have a feeling that I'm missing something - why is the call authorized? Can I make sure the message is still encrypted even though authentication type is set to `Anonymous`? Any help is appreciated.

### Edit

To clarify on this, I tested the service with a client deployed to a machine outside the network on a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MSDN article kind of sums up a lot of security issues relevant to WCF

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx

regarding your specific situation,
the `negotiateServiceCredential="true"` means that you streamline certificate distribution to your clients for message encryption.

This option will only work with windows clients and has some performance problems.
read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647344.aspx
search the topic "streamline certificate distribution" in this page.

Comment: I noticed the performance issues. All the clients are Windows users, also I don't want each user to install a certificate on their machine, so I'll keep the `negotiateServiceCredential` option. I still don't understand what "streamline certificate distribution to your clients" mean. What does this option do? Is this why anonymous calls are authorized?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - Basically what happens is the the client and the server do some negotiontion so that the servers Public Private Key (PPK) will reach the client. I'm unsure if it's a per-session PPK, a timed PPK (probably) or a constant PPK. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Answer (score 0):

Which account do you use to make the call to the service? Allowing anonymous in IIS lets your request pass through to the service and service should authenticate if your caller has credentials that windows understands (Active directory/NTLM). 
In your case, I think you are testing it in your own environment so service responds. Once you deploy it over internet, I doubt your service will allow anybody outside of your domain if you keep clientcredentialtype to windows.
Check these link for securing services on the Internet - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734769.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx

Comment: The application is deployed over the internet, and I use a different account (on a different domain) to make the service call.

Comment: this link should be helpful - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/442be0c8-309e-4000-9311-57189ae7a900/why-is-anonymous-access-required-to-host-wcf-in-iis
"The IIS "directory security" settings only related to transport level security (authentication). If you use message level security mode and authentication, WCF will at startup check that the IIS settings are not conflicting with the WCF config when activating the host. You can then get either "anonymous must be enabled" (non-transport credentials) or "must be turned off" (transport credentials)."

Comment: Interesting article. If that's really the case then I guess I shouldn't be worried about anonymous authentication then.